# Graph not showing when add in %matplotlib notebook using Jupyter in VS Code

Tags: matplotlib, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, ipython-magic

When using Jupyter on VS Code, when I add in %matplotlib notebook, the graph would not show at all

When I start to plot without the magic everything is working fine.
When graph is not showing after adding %matplotlib notebook, removing the magic will not make the graph reappear.
I have to reload the VS code window and restart the kernel.

Comment: Well, one thing in your post is a feature and not a bug. " removing the magic will not make the graph reappear." This is because once you run any `%matplotlib ...` command in a notebook, you switch modes for the backend for all cells. So that is why you need to restart the kernel. No way around that.

Answer (score 0):

Did you install [ipympl](https://github.com/matplotlib/ipympl#ipympl) and try `%matplotlib ipympl` or `%matplotlib widget`, as discussed [here](https://matplotlib.org/ipympl/#basic-example)?

See [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/interactive-matplotlib-in-jupyterlab-no-longer-working/20017/3?u=fomightez) and [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/7607/python-matplotlib-interactive-data/) and [here](https://github.com/matplotlib/ipympl/issues/529#issue-1771786864) for more about getting this to work with VS Code. Especially the bottom section of the [table there](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/interactive-matplotlib-in-jupyterlab-no-longer-working/20017/3?u=fomightez) where the results of testing various approaches in VS Code are shown.